# Dual boot - what happens with "Install alongside windows" ??

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I was directed here from https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/5qowau/dual_boot_what_happens_with_install_alongside/

Here's the question I posted there:

I'm following on line guides on how to set up dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu. Here's a part I haven't found an answer to.

When I get these options:

```
* Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows
* Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu
* Something Else
```

I realize that choosing "Something else" will allow me to set up my swap, root, home, etc partitions as I wish. If I choose the first option though, are there default settings for swap, root, home, etc. that Ubuntu will use? How can I preview the actual disk setup that will be used if I choose the first option?

Also, I see that before starting the Ubuntu install, you need to free up disk space in Windows. That much I understand. But looking at some tutorials like this video (can't post more links here but see my reddit post), when you choose "install alongside windows" it then asks you to divide space between Windows and Ubuntu. See video at about 3:40. Why does it ask about dividing disk space here? If you don't use it all, will the remaining space stay unallocated? EDIT: Or does this option only show up if you didn't allocate free space?  And if so, is there a preferred method (allocate space in Windows or do it during the install), and why is it preferred?

TY!

Comment: *"does this option only show up if you didn't allocate free space"* - **Bingo** but due to the fact that Linux NTFS support isn't perfect, I would always recommend you do it from Windows.

Comment: I recommend that you allocate some free space in Windows, and select Install Alongside. It will automatically create a *dynamic volume* inside the unallocated space, containing one large partition which holds `/`, `/boot` and `/home` as well as a separate swap partition.

Comment: 'Install alongside' will do one of a few actions depending on the partition structure. It is an easy option, but does not give you much control of what is happening. The very fact the you are asking this question makes me think that you should use 'Something else' which means manual configuration. - You should use Windows to shrink the Windows partition, but leave it as unallocated space. Turn off fast boot. Then boot your Ubuntu intall disk and use *gparted* to create the partitions you want for Ubuntu. After that you start the installer.

Comment: So @sudodus you say "'Install alongside' will do one of a few actions depending on the partition structure. "   Is there a way to preview what's going to happen?

Comment: You need to have Windows fast start up or always on hibernation off. The Linux NTFS driver will not mount hibernated NTFS partitions so installer cannot even see that you have Windows. But auto install only gives you / (root) & swap, so you may still want Something Else install option. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: The feature has been modified between versions of Ubuntu, and I can guess what happens, but I am not sure. Maybe you can find some description via the internet, but I think it is better to use the 'Something else' option. If you intend to hibernate you need at least the same size of the swap partitition as the size of RAM in Gibibyte (2^30), so if you have 4 GiB RAM, I would recommend 4.5 GB RAM  (10^9). `4*2^30/10^9=4.3`. I suggest that you use at at least 16 GB for the root partition. Many people use a separate home partition. I use a separate data partition with NTFS, shared with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's a way to preview the partitions setup when you choose to "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows".

I just chose that option, clicked "Continue", and crossed my fingers (I was trying to dual boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04). I was worried at first Ubuntu would overwrite my Windows recovery  partitions, but fortunately, Ubuntu installed itself exactly into the free space I had allocated for it with Windows disk manager (I just followed online tutorials and shrunk my Windows disk); specifically it created one swap partition (same size as my RAM) and another partition for root/home (taking up the rest of the free space). Exactly what I wanted!

UPDATE: Installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a new machine with Windows 10, and there's now a confirmation window once I chose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager", saying

> If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the
> disks. Otherwise, you will be able to make further changes manually.
>
> The partition tables of the following devices are changed:
> `/dev/nvm0n1`
>
> The following partitions are going to be formatted: partition #6 of
> `/dev/nvme0n1 as ext4` # this is the free space I allocated in Windows

So at least I know this installs Ubuntu in the right partition.

Comment: I trusted you, but Ubuntu failed to create the swap and now my windows won't show up on boot menu anymore. RIP. For new users, never select install alongside windows.

Comment: @Christoper Francisco Each computer is different. I have used the option successfully several times.  Sometimes there is a key combination to use for boot options. On my macbook, I just hold down Option when booting.

Comment: (pls work, pls work, pls work, ...)